# How to map an ExpandoObject to a type?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, json.net

I have a dynamic ExpandoObject result with the following key-value pairs:

```
 { id: "1" }
 { product_name: "some name" }
 { product_category: "some category" }
```

And I have a class:

```
public class Product 
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("productName")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("productCategory")]
    public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
```

So can I map the ExpandoObject to this class as a new object? (The ExpandoObject properties come from database columns.)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using expando when you have the JSON like this?

Comment: Doesn't even seem like valid JSON. From my point of view, those are all separate objects with one property each.

Comment: It maps to `IDictionary<string, object>`.  Maybe you like the ToDictionary() extension method.  But realistically you are saying that you don't want to use ExpandoObject.  Lots of ORM libraries around, give Entity Framework a spin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a helper method like this:

```
public static T FromExpando<T>(ExpandoObject expando) where T : class, new()
{
    if (expando == null) return null;

    var properties = typeof(T)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(pi => pi.CanWrite && !pi.GetIndexParameters().Any())
        .ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name.ToLower());

    T obj = new T();
    foreach (var kvp in expando)
    {
        var name = kvp.Key.ToLower().Replace("_", "");
        var val = kvp.Value;
        if (val != null &&
            properties.TryGetValue(name, out PropertyInfo prop) &&
            prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(val.GetType()))
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, val);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
Product prod = FromExpando<Product>(expando);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TUgaW5